# JS & jQuery can't detect html elements, and say's they are undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm pretty new to JS and `jQuery`, and i'm trying to make a subtitles player using them. Unfortunately, i'm stuck in a very early stage.

When I'm trying to select some `HTML` elements through a .js file, it acts like it can't locate the element I'm asking for, and nothing happens. If I try to alert the value or the HTML of the elements, it alerts `undefined`.

So this is the code:

**HTML**

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <script src="jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            body{
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px;           
            }           
            #wrapper{
                width: 150px;
                text-align: center;
                background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%,#75bdd1), color-stop(14%,#75bdd1), color-stop(100%,#2294b3));
                padding: 10px 2px;
            }
            h3{
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            }
            img{
                width: 50px;
                margin: 0 auto;     
            }
            input{
            display: none;          
            }
        </style>


    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <h3>Select subtitles file</h3>
                <img src="browse.png" alt="browse">
        </div>
        <input type="file" accept=".srt" id="file">
    </body>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```
$("div").click(function () {
    console.log('loaded');
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: put your complete script under $(document).ready(function() {}); block

Comment: You are binding event before element is available in the DOM.

Comment: @Or Navo you trying to access the DOM element or variable before its initialized  go here http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_undefined.asp and https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/08/16/understanding-undefined-and-preventing-referenceerrors/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because your `script` tag is *above* the HTML defining the elements that it acts on, it can't find them because they don't exist as of when that code runs. Here's the order in which things are happening in your page:

1. The `html` and `head` elements are created
2. The `meta` element is created and its content noted by the parser
3. The `script` element for jQuery is created
4. The parser **stops** and waits for the jQuery file to load
5. Once loaded, the jQuery file is executed
6. Parsing continues
7. The `script` element for your code is created
8. The parser **stops** and waits for your file to load
9. Once loaded, your script code is run — and doesn't find any elements, because there are no `div` elements yet
10. Parsing continues
11. The browser finishes parsing and building the page, which includes creating the elements you're trying to access in your script

Ways to correct it:

1. Move the `script` elements to the very end, just before the closing `</body>` tag, so all of the elements exist before your code runs. Barring a good reason not to do this, this is usually the best solution.
2. Use jQuery's [`ready` feature](http://api.jquery.com/ready).
3. Use the [`defer` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#attr-script-async) on the script element, but beware that not all browsers support it yet.

But again, if you control where the script elements go, #1 is usually your best bet.

Comment: Okay, it really helped me with the problem and understanding the process, thank you very much!

Comment: Finally, a good answer to my MSO question: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287905/is-there-a-canonical-jquery-document-ready-question#autocomment179053

Answer (score 2):

When you call the .click() method the dom is not fully loaded.
You have to wait till everything in DOM is loaded.So you have to change your script.js to this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("div").click(function () {
    console.log('loaded');
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should execute your script after DOM Ready event. In jquery it makes so:

```
$(function(){
    $("div").click(function () {
            console.log('loaded');
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
$(document).on('click', "element" , function (ev) {
    console.log('loaded');
})
```

})