# Javascript only works with alert ();

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My Code works perfect if I use `alert();` in between. But if I don't use it, the part after //`alert()`; doesn't get executed.

```
function playerleer() {
  $('#pplay').css('background', 'url("images/play.png")');
  $('#player').get(0).pause();
  $('#player').attr('src',null);
  $('.song').html(null);
  alert();
  $('#seekslider').val(0);
  $('#curtimetext').html('0:00');
  $('#durtimetext').html('0:00');
}
```

What could I do?

Thanks for any responds :)

Comment: does your function executes while the DOM building is completed... ie inside `$(function() { .... });` or `$(window).load(function(){ ... });`

Comment: try setting a timeout before executing the second part.

Comment: Doesn't get executed or doesn't do anything?

Comment: I believe it's what Reflective says, it might be executing before all the elements are created and not selectable in time.

Comment: There's not enough information to be sure, but this is probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29716653/js-jquery-cant-detect-html-elements-and-says-they-are-undefined

Comment: Can you make a JSfiddle/JSbin?

Answer (score 2):

Janik have you tried using chrome debugger or the javascript debugger?

basically if you type debugger in your script like so

```
function playerleer() {
  $('#pplay').css('background', 'url("images/play.png")');
  $('#player').get(0).pause();
  $('#player').attr('src',null);
  $('.song').html(null);
  debugger;
  $('#seekslider').val(0);
  $('#curtimetext').html('0:00');
  $('#durtimetext').html('0:00');
}
```

As long as you have the browser debugger open (f12) when you run your javascript the console will hit the debugger and pause, there you can view your variables and then do step by step, alternatively what you can do is open up google chrome, press the f12 key, go to sources, locate your script and then click on the line you want to debug

Here is an image for example [image] Also here is a link to the Chrome debugger tutorial https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging

Answer (score 1):

You can break it into two pieces with a delay. This might work because alert() has the side effect of pausing the code until you acknowledge the alert.

Unfortunately, Javascript has no natural way to pause or sleep, but you can set an alarm clock to call back some code with `setTimeout`. In setTimeout, 1000 = 1sec.  You might need to experiment with the delay value to make it long enough and it could vary among browsers, etc.:

```
function playerleerpart2(){
  $('#seekslider').val(0);
  $('#curtimetext').html('0:00');
  $('#durtimetext').html('0:00');
}

function playerleer() {
  $('#pplay').css('background', 'url("images/play.png")');
  $('#player').get(0).pause();
  $('#player').attr('src',null);
  $('.song').html(null);
  setTimeout(playerleerpart2, 1000);
}
```

If you want to better understand what is happening, you could use `console.log()` like this:

```
 function playerleer() {
  $('#pplay').css('background', 'url("images/play.png")');
  $('#player').get(0).pause();
  $('#player').attr('src',null);
  $('.song').html(null);
  // uncomment and test again alert();
  console.log('#seekslider');
  console.log($('#seekslider'));
  console.log('#curtimetext');
  console.log($('#curtimetext'));
  console.log('#durtimetext');
  console.log($('#durtimetext');
  $('#seekslider').val(0);
  $('#curtimetext').html('0:00');
  $('#durtimetext').html('0:00');
}
```

These objects should all be defined before you can call methods on them.

Comment: Note that there's no reason to reverse the order of the methods as they're parsed fully before execution

Comment: @Basic the order of **execution** is the same as posted.  There is no reversal of anything in execution.

Comment: Yes, it is, just wanted to make it clear to others that you haven't put the 2nd method above the first for any reason other than preference. I still remember languages where that could be an issue (occasionally, I even have to use them. Ugh!)

Comment: @Basic Yes, it might be less confusing to have part1 and part2 functions defined in that order, and then have the main function call part1, and then settimeout with part2.  For debugging purposes the post is OK though.