# javascript append in Php echo?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I try to append something to a div over a Php echo

Includes

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

Php Code

```
<?php echo "<script type='text/javascript' >$('.notificationsBody').prepend('Hello World');</script>"; ?>
```

My Div Code

```
<div class="notificationsBody">TESTING DIV<br></div>
```

Is this possible and if yes why isnt this working ? My Console is empty too. 
If not is there a other way to realize a Div appending over a Php Echo ?

Hint: I need a Php echo if its possible.

This is my complete index.php Page

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"

        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">



<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

</head>
<body>


<?php echo "<script type='text/javascript' >$('.notificationsBody').prepend('Hello World');</script>"; ?>
<div class="notificationsBody">TESTING DIV<br></div>

</body>



</html>
```

What i want at the end is like you have a Class and call the Function

```
<?php echo $myclass->theechofunction(); ?>
```

Then this will echo the Javascript which appending a Div to my Wrapper.

Yes its a bit crazy / difficult but thats what i need.

Thanks for every Answer.

EDIT

The Site Quellcode after calling the site

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>



<script type='text/javascript' >$('.notificationsBody').prepend('Hello World');</script>

<div class="notificationsBody">TESTING DIV<br></div>
```

Comment: Why do you need a PHP echo?

Comment: Looks like you're running it before the page loads https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: I testing at the moment some things :) And  i need Php echo for it

Comment: Can you explain your ultimate intention because the example you've given is quite odd.

Comment: Sure i update a bit my Question

Comment: Please show the outputted HTML in the question

Comment: Then why don't you just echo before the element in the HTML rather than using JavaScript?

Comment: I updated the Question now :)

Comment: Yet you you're loading two versions of jquery, and don't know where to place javascript, or care to learn the basics of jquery.

Comment: Yes cause lazyness :) 
When i testing stuff and all its dont need a perfect html code or something and yes JQ and JS isnt my best Knowledge but getting knowledge means asking ;)

Comment: No it means learning. I gave you a working answer. How you messed it up I don't know.

Comment: Yes too but not only. And i guess this here i for asking or ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two problems. First, you're loading two versions of jQuery, that will probably cause conflicts. Either load jQuery from ajax.googleapis.com or code.jquery.com, but not both.

Second, the Javascript that tries to append to `.notificationBody` is running before you add that element to the DOM. There are two ways to solve this: either move the code that echoes the `<script>` tag to after you echo the `.notificationBody` DIV, or run your code in the `$(document).ready()` handler, which runs after the DOM is completely loaded:

```
<?php echo "<script type='text/javascript' >
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.notificationsBody').prepend('Hello World');
    });
    </script>";
?>
```

See [JS & jQuery can't detect html elements, and say's they are undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29716653/js-jquery-cant-detect-html-elements-and-says-they-are-undefined)