# JQuery AJAX throws no error but doesn't work as well

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services

I have this JQuery AJAX code that calls a ASP.NET Web Service method with the signature:
   "public bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)"
It should return true/false. The AJAX throws no error but doesn't work as well.

```
<script>
       $('#btn').click(function () {
                var a=$('#name').val(), b=$('#pass').val();
                $.ajax({
                    url:'http://localhost:22664/StockServices.asmx/ValidateUser',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ username: a, password: b }),
                    dataType: "json",
                    method: 'post',
                    success: function (data) {

                        alert("Msg: " + data.d);

                    }, error: function (err) { alert("failed"); 
                    console.log(err); }
                });
            });
    </script>
```

Comment: What does console show up?

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work so well ?

Comment: console is blank ... that's what I said... throws no error

Comment: @loneshark99 I said doesn't  work as well i.e., it doesn't show any errors but doesn't even work

Comment: Does your method call from Ajax?

Comment: @Div yea, JQuery AJAX

Comment: possibly a CORS issue if `http://localhost:22664` is a different origin to the page you're calling from - more likely is that script is run before the button is in the DOM - therefore, never bound to the click event (jquery hides these basic errors of trying to access a DOM element before it's defined) - add `alert($('#btn').length);` just before the first line of you script, and if it alerts `0` - then you're running the script too early ... enclose in `$(function() {` ... your script goes here ... `});`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JS & jQuery can't detect html elements, and say's they are undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29716653/js-jquery-cant-detect-html-elements-and-says-they-are-undefined)

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 0):

To enable your `.asmx` service to be called from javascript you need to add this attribute to the `.asmx` service definition:

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
```

So your complete service may look something like this:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class StockServices : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    public bool ValidateUser(string username,string password)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Also be careful using `url:'http://localhost:22664/StockServices.asmx/ValidateUser'` because when this code is deployed to production it will no longer work.You may want to change it to:

`url: 'StockServices.asmx/ValidateUser'`

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that in your ajax call, you are using:

```
$.ajax({
   ...
   method: 'post',
   ...
});
```

You should try:

```
$.ajax({
   ...
   type: 'post',
   ...
});
```

I found the following snippet from [this link](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

> type (default: 'GET')
>
> Type: String An alias for method. You should use
>   type if you're using versions of jQuery prior to 1.9.0.

Could it be that you are using an old version of jQuery which does not accept `method` but accepts `type`?