# Creating selector menu from array of objects

Tags: jquery, arrays, object

I'm trying to create a selector menu from an array of ojbects. Here is a sample of the object:

```
let states = [
      {id: 1, state: "Alabama", district: "1st District", url:"Alabama_1st.pdf"},
      {id: 2, state: "Alabama", district: "2nd District", url:"Alabama_1st.pdf"},
      {id: 3, state: "Alabama", district: "3rd District", url:"Alabama_1st.pdf"},
      {id: 4, state: "Alabama", district: "4th District", url:"Alabama_1st.pdf"},
      {id: 5, state: "Alabama", district: "5th District", url:"Alabama_1st.pdf"},
      {id: 6, state: "Alabama", district: "6th District", url:"Alabama_1st.pdf"},
      {id: 7, state: "Alabama", district: "7th District", url:"Alabama_1st.pdf"},
      {id: 9, state: "Alaska", district: "Statewide District", url:"Alaska_1st.pdf"},
      {id: 10, state: "Arizona", district: "1st District", url:"Arizona_1st.pdf"},
      {id: 11, state: "Arizona", district: "2nd District", url:"Arizona.2nd.pdf"},
      {id: 12, state: "Arizona", district: "3rd District", url:"Arizona_3rd.pdf"},
```

I have the following jQuery so far but am struggling to get the states.state and states.district to populate in my selector menu. My console log is coming back correct so I know I am accessing the data, just can't get it to append to my selector menu.

```
<script>         
        for(let i = 0; i < states.length; i++) {
           if(states[i].id > 0){
             $("#listed_states").append(states[i].state +" "+ states[i].district);
              console.log(states[i].state +" "+ states[i].district);
            }
          }
</script>

<body>

    <select>
      <option>Find Your District Here<option>
      <option id="listed_states"> <option>
    </select>
</body>
```

I'll be adding an .change() function to this after it fires to load a url with a _target.

Comment: Move the js code to a line before `</body>` or use `$(document).ready()`, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29716708/6591929)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should append to the select element, not the option.  You also need to create the option element in jQuery.

**HTML**

```
<select id="listed_states">
  <option>Find Your District Here</option>
</select>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  for (let i = 0; i < states.length; i++) {
    if (states[i].id > 0) {
      var option = $("<option>", {
        text: states[i].state + " " + states[i].district,
        value: states[i].id
      });
      $('#listed_states').append($(option));
    }
  }
});
```

Don't forget to wrap your code that is appending the options in `$(document).ready` so that it waits for the DOM to load before executing (since you are appending to an element in the DOM)

Here is a Fiddle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/zephyr_hex/bztgwubf/

Comment: You're thebomb.com! Thanks for the help. Worked like a charm. 
I did something like this previously in Ruby but added the id to my option and that worked. Do you know why it has to be on the select and not the option?

Comment: @OsuDani :  If you append to the option, you are adding something to the option that has the id.  You could append AFTER the option with the id.

Comment: Gotcha - Thanks for the explainer.

Answer (score 1):

Some issues:

- The `id` should be on the `select` element, not on the `option` element, which you don't need.
- The `option` tags do not have a closing tag: you actually open a second one each time
- The code should execute when the document has loaded
- You need to wrap the texts in `option` tags

You can use `append` once, and provide it an array:

```js
let states = [ {id: 1, state: "Alabama", district: "1st District", url:"Alabama_1st.pdf"}, {id: 2, state: "Alabama", district: "2nd District", url:"Alabama_1st.pdf"}, {id: 3, state: "Alabama", district: "3rd District", url:"Alabama_1st.pdf"}, {id: 4, state: "Alabama", district: "4th District", url:"Alabama_1st.pdf"}, {id: 5, state: "Alabama", district: "5th District", url:"Alabama_1st.pdf"}, {id: 6, state: "Alabama", district: "6th District", url:"Alabama_1st.pdf"}, {id: 7, state: "Alabama", district: "7th District", url:"Alabama_1st.pdf"}, {id: 9, state: "Alaska", district: "Statewide District", url:"Alaska_1st.pdf"}, {id: 10, state: "Arizona", district: "1st District", url:"Arizona_1st.pdf"}, {id: 11, state: "Arizona", district: "2nd District", url:"Arizona.2nd.pdf"}, {id: 12, state: "Arizona", district: "3rd District", url:"Arizona_3rd.pdf"}];

$(function () {      
    $("#listed_states").append(
        $.map(states, function (state) {
            return $('<option>').text(state.state + " " + state.district);
        })
    );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="listed_states">
    <option>Find Your District Here</option>
</select>
```