# JQuery code that hides and shows divs doesn't work when integrated with my live site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Works fine here and on JSFiddle but when I try to integrate the code into my WooCommerce site, it doesn't do a thing.

My code is fairly simple, it simply checks the dimensions of an image and shows/hides divs with the appropriate messages based on the results of the check.

[**Here is the live site.**](https://victoryposters.com/product/speed/)

```js
var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

$("#filecheck").change(function() {
  var file, img;

  if ((file = this.files[0])) {
    img = new Image();

    img.onload = function() {
      if (this.width < 1800 && this.height < 1800) {
        $('.pass').css('display', 'none');
  $('.fail').css('display', 'block');
      }
      
      else {
        $('.pass').css('display', 'block');
  $('.fail').css('display', 'none');
      }
    };
    img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(file);
  }
});
```

```css
.pass {
  display: none;
}

.fail {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="filecheck" />
<div class="pass">
image quality good
</div>

<div class="fail">
image quality too low
</div>
```

Can anyone see anything that I've done wrong here? It's probably something really basic but I'm pretty new to this.

Comment: I see several JavaScript errors on your live site. They may or may not be related to the code you've posted here, but they might be causing problems.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JS & jQuery can't detect html elements, and say's they are undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29716653/js-jquery-cant-detect-html-elements-and-says-they-are-undefined)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you might be attaching the handler before the object exists in the DOM. If I inject your script into the page after it loads (i.e., copy and paste it into the JavaScript console), then it seems to work.

Three things you could try:

You could try attaching the listener to `document` first, which is always there, and then use the `#filecheck` selector:

```
$(document).on('change', '#filecheck', function () {
     // Your code here
});
```

This might not be the best performance-wise, but could do the trick.

You could also try wrapping the code in a `ready()` handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Your event handler code
});
```

You could also try moving your file handling script to the end of the document body and see if that works.

Comment: What indicates that handlers are attached before objects exist in the DOM? I see scripts at the end of the document.

Comment: The OP's file handler code doesn't run initially. If I enter the same exact code into the JS console after the page loads, the code works as expected. My thinking was a potential cause of that behavior could be attaching to an element that is not yet loaded. I also thought perhaps another handler might be overriding the original, but couldn't find any evidence of that. Perhaps I missed it though?

Comment: I see what you mean; thanks for explaining! I now see that the script in question is indeed at the top of the document, before `#filecheck` exists in the DOM. Waiting for the document to be ready (or moving the script to the bottom) [solves the issue](https://jsfiddle.net/z5fxb9dk/).

Comment: After wrapping the code in the .ready(function), everything worked as it should! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your Custom.js has this kind of Code 
     $( window ).load( et_all_elements_loaded );

Please replace that code with the below one
     $( window ).on("load", et_all_elements_loaded );

Comment: Do the same thing to unload functions also

Answer (score 0):

There is confliction issue.

Please replace `jQuery` with `$` and let me know.

Hope this help.

```
var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

jQuery("#filecheck").change(function() {
  var file, img;

  if ((file = this.files[0])) {
    img = new Image();

    img.onload = function() {
      if (this.width < 1800 && this.height < 1800) {
        jQuery('.pass').css('display', 'none');
        jQuery('.fail').css('display', 'block');
      }

      else {
        jQuery('.pass').css('display', 'block');
        jQuery('.fail').css('display', 'none');
      }
    };
    img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(file);
  }
});
```

Comment: What indicates that there's a library conflict?